# Getting nfsstat-like statistics for ext3 and other filesystems

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, hook, kernel

For those not familiar with nfsstat: it basically just counts the number of calls to specific functions. This way one can get statistics about NFS I/O operations and thus use them to analyze performance.

I would like to do something like that in a more general fashion. I'd like to somehow count the number of e.g. "stat" calls. If possible a count per mount point. I am however not sure where to start. I have sufficient programming skills using C against the libc library, but lacking knowlegde of the Linux kernel.

I feel this is supposed to be done via a loadable kernel module but I'm not sure the kernel API provides the possibilities to hook into those kinds of system calls. Or should I use inotify for this (doesn't monitor stat calls)?

Where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To watch all the system calls happening on the system, you can use the [Linux audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to watch for a specific syscall. You can set up filters such as restricting the watch to a directory tree. The documentation is rather sparse; start with the [auditctl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/auditctl.8.html), or perhaps [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html). Most recent distributions ship an `auditd` package. Install it and make sure the `auditd` daemon is running, then do

```
auditctl -A exit,always -F dir=/mount/point -S stat
```

and watch the calls get logged in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` (or wherever your distribution has set this up).

At the other extreme, if you're only interested in the system calls made by a particular process (and optionally its subprocesses), use [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace).

```
strace -s9999 -estrace -f mycommand
```

In between, if you want to watch some of the filesystem accesses of a bunch of programs, make them access the files you're concerned about through [loggedfs](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/). This is a stackable filesystem: it provides an alternate view of an existing directory tree. It can log every operation, has rich filters and comes with reasonable documentation.

Comment: Thanks, this will get me on my way!